# 'ElementNotVisibleException' Unable to click button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

A rather 'tricky' question that makes my head spin. I'm unable to click a button while using Selenium.

```
Css selector property: ValidateOrderForm > span > button
Xpath: #//*[@id="ValidateOrderForm"]/span/button
```

Attempts:

```
d.find_elements_by_xpath('ValidateOrderForm')[1].clear()
d.find_elements_by_id('ValidateOrderForm')[0].click()
d.find_element_by_css_selector("button.call-to-action").click()
```

And really everything in between.
[image]

[image]

Update: it gives the following error

ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable

Comment: Do you get any errors? Or it just doesn't click?

Comment: It gives a ElementNotVisibleException with some attempts

Comment: Try `print(len(d.find_elements_by_css_selector("button.call-to-action")))`. Is it `1`?

Comment: @Andersson; it gives value 3

Comment: That means that you might handle hidden button instead of the one you really need... Try more specific selector, like `//span/button[.="Bevestigen"]`... If it also doesn't work, share more HTML (as text, not as image)

Comment: Can you share the full(er) HTML of the page you are testing?

Comment: @Andersson You got this, you legend! Solution: d.find_element_by_xpath("//span/button[.='Bevestigen']").click()